# SQLAlchemy show me that "AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'columns'"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, attributes

I am building a small project use python+Flask+SQLAlchemy, I make a model file following:

```
################# start of models.py #####################
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Sequence, Date, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from dk.database import Base
import datetime

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('seq_user_id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True, index = True, nullable = False)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True, index = True, nullable = False)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable = False)

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)

class Session(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'session'
    id = Column(String(128), primary_key = True, nullable = False)
    user_name = Column(String(30), nullable = False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship('User', backref=backref('session', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Session %r>' % (self.id)
################# end of models.py #####################
```

and I build a initial file following:

```
################# start of __init__.py #################
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config') #load database config information
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
################# end of __init__.py #################
```

when I run the "init_db()" in script, tables built to database successful.
but when I want to see the SQL script then I run the "print CreateTable(User)" in script, the system show follwing errors:

```
  File "/home/jacky/flaskcode/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 3361, in __init__
    for column in element.columns
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'columns'
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem!

Comment: Why *are* you calling `CreateTable` on the `User` object? What do you expect to happen? `CreateTable` expects a `Table` object, not a declarative base object.

Comment: Hi Martijn Pieters, I want to call print CreateTable(User) because I want to see the SQL script of create table generated from SQLAlchemy, I want to confirm whether it is what I want. And I learn the usage of function CreateTable() from SQLAlchemy's offical document. And I try to use CreateTable(__users__), but system told me that object __users__ do not exist.

Comment: That won't work; you'd be better on switching on echoing (passing `echo=True` on connection to the database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in a *`Table`* object for `CreateTable()`:

```
CreateTable(User.__table__)
```

but if you wanted to see the SQL statements that SQLAlchemy issues you are better off switching on echoing by setting [`echo=True` when creating the connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api).

The Flask SQLAlchemy integration layer supports a [`SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` option](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html#configuration-keys) to set that flag.

Comment: And I was not use flask-SQLAlchemy but SQLAlchemy, becaue I found that some function is not inheritate to flask-SQLAlchemy, for example: CreateTable()